# Class Inheritance in C# (possibly generics)

Tags: c#, object-oriented, design-patterns, inheritance

I'm working on a segment of code where it runs a number of tasks and then combine individual task results to construct a complete task result object, there's no concurrency involved so it's purely a question of the best use of class inheritance/pattern.

Below is the skeleton of the code I've written, it loops through `IList<ITask>` where each `ITask` returns an `ITaskResult`, the main method will then have to examine the type of each `ITaskResult` and set the property on `CompleteTaskResult` accordingly.

The goal is to keep the code easy to understand and easy to add new Task/TaskResult.

What I'm not happy about is the part where it has to check the type of `ITaskResult` individually and then set the value on `CompleteTaskResult`, it feels a little cumbersome with lots of repetitions.

Is there a better way to structure this code?

Thanks.

```
        public interface ITask
        {
            ITaskResult Execute();
        }

        public class AlphaTask : ITask
        {
            public ITaskResult Execute()
            {
                return new AlphaTaskResult();
            }
        }

        public class BetaTask : ITask
        {
            public ITaskResult Execute()
            {
                return new BetaTaskResult();
            }
        }

        public class GammaTask : ITask
        {
            public ITaskResult Execute()
            {
                return new GammaTaskResult();
            }
        }

        public interface ITaskResult
        {
        }

        public class AlphaTaskResult : ITaskResult
        {
        }

        public class BetaTaskResult : ITaskResult
        {
        }

        public class GammaTaskResult : ITaskResult
        {
        }

        public class CompleteTaskResult
        {
            public AlphaTaskResult AlphaTaskResult { get; set; }
            public BetaTaskResult BetaTaskResult { get; set; }
            public GammaTaskResult GammaTaskResult { get; set; }
        }

        static void Main(IList<ITask> tasks)
        {
            var taskResults = tasks.Select(x => x.Execute());

            var completeTaskResult = new CompleteTaskResult();

            foreach (var taskResult in taskResults)
            {
                if (taskResult is AlphaTaskResult alphaTaskResult)
                {
                    completeTaskResult.AlphaTaskResult = alphaTaskResult;
                    continue;
                }

                if (taskResult is BetaTaskResult betaTaskResult)
                {
                    completeTaskResult.BetaTaskResult = betaTaskResult;
                    continue;
                }

                if (taskResult is GammaTaskResult gammaTaskResult)
                {
                    completeTaskResult.GammaTaskResult = gammaTaskResult;
                    continue;
                }
                throw new InvalidOperationException("unsupported task")
            }

        }
```

Edit: The intention is one can pass a number of tasks in the form of `IList<ITask>` to the library and then retrieve concrete results back from `CompleteTaskResult` `CompleteTaskResult` may have null properties if no specific tasks related to the properties were executed. The main caller is well aware of what concrete type of `ITask` were sent in so it also knows what properties from `CompleteTaskResult` to query for the results

Comment: Why does `CompleteTaskResult` contain specific result types, instead of a list of `ITaskResult`s? If that is intentional, then why does `Main` accept a list of `ITask`s, instead of specific task types whose output match the properties in `CompleteTaskResult`? (Note that your code is fairly abstract. That tends to result in downvotes due to lack of concrete context).

Comment: Your question lacks concrete context about your specific design desicions. Why do you need to know the specific type of `ITaskResult` at all. Give it a meaningful interface, with properties and functions you can use independently of the underlying type. Note that asking for reviewing stub code like that is _off-topic_ here. – πάντα ῥεῖ 8 mins ago

Comment: @PieterWitvoet The idea is that the caller of `main` can send in any number of `ITask` and then receive the results from `CompleteTaskResult` by querying specific result types. `CompleteTaskResult` is the client-facing side of object so it contains concrete types. Without the use of `List<ITask>`, I'm not sure the best way to achieve that.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ `CompleteTaskResult` is what the end-user will interact with so it needs to have some concrete types.  Sorry if the code lacks sufficient context, this is what I have in mind so I'm seeking some early advise (I know this is not perfect)

Comment: @Godsent Generally we only review fully working code for improvement here. If you have a specific question regarding the usage of the [tag:design-patterns] then that tag is appropriate.

Comment: This code is too sketchy and hypothetical to review. Foo/bar examples are not acceptable on Code Review. What do these tasks have in common, and how do they differ? You need to post your real code, or at least something plausibly realistic, so that we can give you proper advice. Please see [ask].

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ thanks, I'll ask for advise again after I get it fully working, my apologies.

Comment: @Godsent: that makes little sense. If your method accepts a list of `ITask`, then it should return a list of `ITaskResult` (if necessary, a caller could use Linq's `OfType<T>` to fetch specific results). If it specifically returns only an alpha, beta and gamma result, then it should accept only an alpha, beta and gamma task. Otherwise, what about callers that pass in omega tasks? Or multiple alpha tasks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply add the task results to a collection. Different types of collections can be used:

1. `List<ITaskResult>`: You can add several results of the same type. You must enumerate to find a task of a specific type.
2. `Dictionary<Type, ITaskResult>`: Each task result type can be added only once. You can query specific task types.

   ```
   if (results.TryGetValue(typeof(BetaTaskResult), out ITaskResult taskResult)) {
       ...
   }
   ```

   or if you know a result is there for sure:

   ```
   ITaskResult taskResult = results[typeof(BetaTaskResult)];
   ```

   Of course, you can also use other types of keys, like enums or strings.
3. `Dictionary<Type, List<ITaskResult>>`: Each task result type can be added several times. You can query specific task result types. Handling is a bit more complex.

If you want to access members who are not part of the interface, you must cast the result to specific types.

```
// Assuming each result type occurs only once.
Dictionary<Type, ITaskResult> results = tasks
    .Select(x => x.Execute())
    .ToDictionary(r => r.GetType()); // alternative: .ToList()
```

---

If you prefer to keep your current solution, you can simplify it a bit. This will enumerate the tasks several times; however, this is acceptable, because you have a very small number of tasks.

```
var taskResults = tasks
    .Select(x => x.Execute())
    .ToList();
var completeTaskResult = new CompleteTaskResult {
   AlphaTaskResult = taskResults.OfType<AlphaTaskResult>().FirstOrDefault(),
   BetaTaskResult  = taskResults.OfType<BetaTaskResult>().FirstOrDefault(),
   GammaTaskResult = taskResults.OfType<GammaTaskResult>().FirstOrDefault(),
};
```

It is important to call `.ToList()`, otherwise this would execute the tasks several times.

See also: [Lazy Evaluation (and in contrast, Eager Evaluation)](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericwhite/2006/10/04/lazy-evaluation-and-in-contrast-eager-evaluation/)

Comment: I up-voted, but in the future I would refrain from answering questions that are clearly off-topic. @see https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer and https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask